# yii - urlManager : how redirect route to pattern

Tags: yii

I've got urlManager rules:

```
...
'/<slug:(nasha-glavnaya-zagolovok)>' => 'page/page/show',
'/pages/<slug>' => 'page/page/show',
...
```

all fine.
When I enter to address

```
/nasha-glavnaya-zagolovok
```

it opens the page i need
But if I try to open page

```
/pages/nasha-glavnaya-zagolovok
```

it also opens the page I need

But content of pages are same.

How i can redirect (with 301 header) from **route** to **pattern** if any rule in urlManager mathced?

Comment: Don't be surprise that content is the same since you are using the same controller action... What do you want to do exactly ??

Comment: I knew that they same.
But how about, to select last rule and dont go to others?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot give you the complete answer, but you can work make it work like this...

you can use a rule that sends the request to an action which job is just to redirect using CController::redirect()

replace this

```
'/<slug:(nasha-glavnaya-zagolovok)>' => 'page/page/show',
'/pages/<slug>' => 'page/page/show',
```

with this

```
'/<slug:(nasha-glavnaya-zagolovok)>' => 'page/page/show',
'/pages/<slug>' => 'site/redirect',
```

and redirect the user to /$slug in the 'site/redirect' action

update: you can make it work by writing a new url rule which extends CBaseUrlRule, not sure if you care to take the time to do that if this is the only redirect you want to do though

Comment: and how can i get information, thant some short url is exist?
By this manipulations im going to have some short url to some articles, not all of them, but most of them

Comment: This is a new, unrelated question. Inside the action that redirects the user you can do anything any action can do, check if the article exists, if it doesn't throw an exception else redirect the user to the article page. This will add some overhead (which you will probably not even notice unless it's a very large scale project)

Comment: i think, with action - not good idea. Because, way with action I know, but what about urlManager, this is very good question.

Comment: It would be good, if there is some action, like .htaccess has
    "...[L]"
like this Last rule, and dont go to others!